# Why does placing echom in vimrc as part of a mapping cause it to echo on load?

Tags: vimrc

As a test, I have created a one line `.vimrc` file and have an empty `.vim/` directory. The `.vimrc` file is:

```
nnoremap <leader>fed :e ~/vimrc.test<CR> | echom "opening vimrc . . ."
```

On `vim` startup, it displays the `opening vimrc` text, then waits for input.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You need a backslash before your pipe `\|` in order for it all to be considered part of the `nnoremap` command. Also, you'll want to add a colon before `echom` and add another `<CR>` at the end. Try:

```
nnoremap <leader>fed :e ~/vimrc.test<CR>\|:echom "opening vimrc . . ."<CR>
```

Comment: That didn't work.  That having been said I found a work around solution to moving the echom command to the bottom of the .vimrc file

Comment: @DrewM `echom` needs to be `:echom`, you'll need two `<CR>`s, and you can't have spaces around the `\|`; I've updated the answer. Also see [`:help map-bar`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-bar) by the way.